# Help with minipage/colum space

Tags: spacing, graphics, minipage, two-column, typewriter

I am currently making a non-professional document in latex, I am using the typewriter package.
I'm trying to put two photos (one below the other) and right next to them, as if it were another column, put some text.
Below this put ornaments from The Ornaments package, so I can't divide the page into columns.
At the time of writing the text, it "invades" the space of the photos and that does not look good.

```
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.9\textwidth}
       \begin{minipage}[t]{0.25\textwidth}
          \includegraphics[width=1.2\linewidth]{f/brujitau.png} 
       \end{minipage}
       \hfill ""example text,\\ 
       \hfill example text."\\
       \hfill "example text,\\ 
       \hfill example text."\\
       \begin{minipage}[t]{0.25\textwidth}
          \includegraphics[width=1.2\linewidth]{f/brud.png} 
       \end{minipage}
\end{minipage}
\begin{center}
    \protect\pgfornament[anchor=south,width=0.5cm, color=pink]                                             
     {4}\pgfornament[anchor=south,width=0.5cm, color=pink]                           
     {4}\pgfornament[anchor=south,width=0.5cm, color=pink] 
     {4}\pgfornament[anchor=south,width=0.5cm,symmetry=v, color=pink] 
     {4}\pgfornament[anchor=south,width=0.5cm,symmetry=v, color=pink] 
     {4}\pgfornament[anchor=south,width=0.5cm,symmetry=v, color=pink]{4}
\end{center}
```

[image]

I am new using this kind of packages and I would appreciate if you help me solving this
(Also if you know how to fix the problem of the difference in spacing between the first song and the second, I would appreciate it.)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.